# Do a for each loop in a folder in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a folder with csv files. For now I have to go manually and write manually each file. Is it somehow to get all the files and do a for loop? This is the current code I have and thank you so much!

```
static List<Widget> getPlates(String file) {
    List<Widget> listWidgets = [];
    loadAsset('assets/$file.csv').then((dynamic output) {
      List<String> list = output.split('\n');
      for (int i = 1; i < list.length - 1; i++) {
        List<String> sublist = list[i].split(';');
        listWidgets.add(CardPlate(
          name: sublist[0],
          ingredients: sublist[1],
          price: sublist[2],
        ));
      }
    });

    return listWidgets;
  }

  static Future<String> loadAsset(String path) async {
    return await rootBundle.loadString(path);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking something like this, or even more indepth?

```dart
output.split('\n').forEach((String entry) {
  List<String> sublist = entry.split(';');
    listWidgets.add(CardPlate(
    name: sublist[0],
    ingredients: sublist[1],
    price: sublist[2],
  ));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'dart:convert';

static final reg = RegExp(r'assets/\w+\.csv'); //check for all files within assets, not including subfolders

static List<Widget> getPlater() async{
  List<Widget> listWidgets = [];

  var myAssets = await rootBundle.loadString('AssetManifest.json'); //file generated by flutter which you can read up through the default bundle
  Map<String, dynamic> map = json.decode(myAssets);
  map.removeWhere((key, value) => !key.contains(reg)); //remove all keys that aren't csv files
  for(String path in map.keys){
    var output = await rootBundle.loadString(path);
    List<String> list = output.split('\n');
    for (int i = 1; i < list.length - 1; i++) {
       List<String> sublist = list[i].split(';');
       listWidgets.add(CardPlate(
         name: sublist[0],
         ingredients: sublist[1],
           price: sublist[2],
       ));
    }
  }

  return listWidgets;
}
```